# javascript/jQuery passing arguments in a method

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, arguments

How can I pass argument in this code

```
$table += "<td>" + "<a href='#' onclick='myFunction(HERE_I_need_to_pass_an_argument);'>" + items[i].senderID +"</a>" +"------"+ items[i].startTime +"</td>";

function myFunction (myVariable) {
 // my other logic goes here
}
```

can you help me writing an alert on that like this:

```
alertValue = 10;
$table += "<td>" + "<a href='#' onclick='alert(alertValue );'>" + items[i].senderID +"</a>" +"------"+ items[i].startTime +"</td>";

function myFunction (myVariable) {
 // my other logic goes here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$table += "<td>" + "<a href='#' onclick='alert("+alertValue+");'>" + items[i].senderID +"</a>" +"------"+ items[i].startTime +"</td>";
```

Comment: thank you so much, always stuck in quotes and double quotes ... aaagghhh ... anyway, that worked a big Thank You

Comment: I will accept your answer later, SOF did not allow me to accept your answer now, says after 8 min :-)